Why aren't all standard containers noexcept move constructible?
I'm surprised that, aside from std::vector and std::basic_string, container types are allowed to throw exceptions from their move constructor. Since C++17, their move assignment operator has been noexcept (provided the allocators are equal and other reasonable constraints are met), so why don't the move constructors offer the same exception guarantee?
For context, I've always assumed that moving objects is cheap. But the lack of noexcept is a red flag that hints at allocation under the hood. Why would an implementation allocate during move construction? I can't think of a good reason, except for some misguided desire to keep the moved-from object in a "valid" state (beyond simply being destructible and assignable).

Related: Why aren't container move assignment operators noexcept?

And here is an authoritative answer specifically for std::map. Similar reasoning probably applies to all, or is just done for consistency: Why is std::map's move constructor not noexcept?

Thanks. So they decided to keep the moved-from map in a "valid" state beyond what is necessary (destruction and assignment), which unfortunately leads to noexcept inconsistency and surprising allocations. Presumably, move assignment doesn't have the same problem since it just swaps the objects.

The reason is probably  a historical artefact.  Before C++11, neither noexcept nor move constructors existed, quite a few constructors of standard containers (e.g. copy construction) were permitted to throw, and - when C++11 came along - some existing implementation approaches would have required significant rework (i.e. cost to vendors) to support noexcept move construction.   When the committee votes on changes to the standard, one of the basic tenets is to avoid substantial collateral breakage of existing code or implementations.

C++17 having noexcept assignment already put some limits on implementations (no small object optimization). It was a step in the right direction, too bad the committee didn't go all the way. There wouldn't be much rework for library vendors if the standard had codified the state of moved-from objects to support destruction, assignment, and swap instead of some nebulous "valid but unspecified state". If it's cheap for a type to specify valid state after move, it can do so, but this shouldn't be mandatory for standard types.
